# MySQL How to split string from column by " " and insert result separated by , into another column?

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask **how to split string from column (all rows in table) by " " and insert result separated by , into another column in same table**?

Many thanks for any advice.

**Table struct example:**

```
------------------------------------------
| Original string | Spliced  string       |
------------------------------------------
| Some string 001 | Some,String,001       |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to "split" a string on a delimiter, I'd likely make use of the nifty `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function. But there are a few quirks to be aware of.

The approach I would take would certainly be to write a SELECT statement first. That would include the expression(s) in the SELECT list that return the "separated" values that I wanted to assign to another column. I'd get those expressions tested using a SELECT statement, before I wrote an UPDATE statement.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.column_i_want_to_split
     , expr1
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.id
```

To test specific cases, I'd make use of an inline view

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.note
     , t.val
     , expr1
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id, 'empty string test' AS note, '' AS val
         UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'null', NULL
         UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'one space', ' '
         UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'four spaces', '    '
         UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'test5', ' abc def '
         UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'test6', 'g  hi kl  m'
       ) t
   ORDER BY t.id
```

Once I had the expression(s) returning the values I want to assign to another column, I'd convert the SELECT into an UPDATE statement. To process all rows, omit the WHERE clause.

```
 UPDATE mytable t
    SET t.another_column = expr1
```

Without a more definitive specification, or at least some concrete examples of what you are attempting to achieve, we're just guessing. Given only a general description of the problem, all we can offer is some general advice.